# Не работает переключение active у пунктов меню при скроллинге по секциям

Tags: bootstrap, menu, прокрутка, fullpage

На Bootstrap + плагин Fullpage набросан макет лендинга. Скроллинг от Fullpage работает как нужно, но ссылки в меню при прокручивании по секциям не становятся активными. Все библиотеки стоковые, не измененные. Различные манипуляции с CSS не дали результата. Подскажите, где копать и как правильно оформить active hover в CSS

Код страницы

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <!-- Таблица стилей Bootstrap -->
  <link href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Основная таблица стилей -->
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CSS файл плагина fullpage -->
  <link href="libs/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>


      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <li class="nav navbar-left"><img height="50px" src="img/aziz.png"/></li>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navigation">
            <li data-menuanchor="#home"><a href="#home">Главная</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="more"><a href="#more">Подробнее</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="why"><a href="#why">Почему мы?</a></li>            
            <li data-menuanchor="faq"><a href="#faq">F.A.Q.</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="video"><a href="#video">Видео</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="franchise"><a href="#franchise">Сотрудничество</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="contact"><a href="#contact">Контакты</a></li>


          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">
        <li>Телефон горячей линии: 8(800)555-35-35</li>
      </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

  <div id="fullpage">
    <section class="section" data-anchor="home">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Главная</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
<section class="section" data-anchor="more">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Подробнее</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section" data-anchor="why">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Почему мы</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section" data-anchor="faq">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Вопросы-ответы</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section" data-anchor="video">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Видео</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section" data-anchor="franchise">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Сотрудничество</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section" data-anchor="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Контакты</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>
  <!-- Библиотека jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- js файлы плагина fullpage -->
  <script src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/fullpage/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/fullpage/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/fullpage/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#fullpage').fullpage();
      anchors: ['home', 'more', 'faq', 'video', 'franchise', 'contact'];
      menu: '#navigation';
    });
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Код css

```
/*Фон для секций*/

.section:home {
  background: #eee;
}

.section:more {
  background: #eee;
}

.section:last-child {
  background: #333;
}
```

Comment: А на секции `home` якорь активен?

Comment: Нет. Принудительно в коде её можно сделать активной, но плагин не изменяет ни секции, делая их активными, ни пункты меню (при прокручивании если посмотреть исходный код - нуль изменений)

Comment: А что-нибудь в консоли есть?

Comment: Никакие ошибки не диагностировались. Пока что туплю, не понимаю. После "перекура" просмотрю всё тщательно

Comment: А пробовали помимо `data-anchor` давать аттрибут `id`, у вас ведь ссылки не будут вести на эти секции(при нажатии)

Comment: Ну т.е. `<section class="section" data-anchor="why" id="why">...</section>`

Comment: И `css` селекторы у вас нерабочие, потому-как вы воздействуете через несуществующий псевдокласс. Попробуйте опять таки дать `id` вашим секциям, и делать что-то вроде `#why{...}`

Comment: Разобрался. Оказались корявые исходники скриптов, которые не давали связать элементы, а позже сдвигали секции со своих мест.

Comment: @Klimenkomud большое спасибо за отзывчивость